# Debugging pygls language server extensions in VSCode

Tags: vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol, python-language-server

I am working on Python-based language server (for a domain-specific lanaguage) and VSCode extension using pygls. I have followed the steps in the [README](https://github.com/openlawlibrary/pygls/blob/main/examples/vscode-playground/README.md) and am trying to follow the [tutorial](https://pygls.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html#tutorial). The tutorial suggests setting a VSCode breakpoint in the `completion` function in the [sample code](https://github.com/openlawlibrary/pygls/blob/main/examples/servers/json_server.py) (though I think it's a mistake, `completions` is correct), but the breakpoint never triggers. I've tried a number of things to no avail -- and I'm also fundamentally not understanding how a node process would trigger a python breakpoint anyway. Doing a `print` or other similar logging works well, so I know the code is being executed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you get anywhere on this? I've being struggling to get it to work too?